# Cant upgrade Expo CLI

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I am facing a problem while upgrading the expo cli.

After running `npm install -g expo-cli` it runs the command for like 3-5 min and then it exits with the error ``` errno: -4048``code: EPERM ```

I tried running the VSCode terminal as an Admin and also tried installing it with CMD ran as Admninistrator same Errors.

Some additional info text:

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),

npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

I also closed the Emmulator and Vscode while installing it but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the fix for anybody having the same issue was to kill the `adb.exe` process. After that it ran faster and without an error!